# Can I disable the PS4's profanity filter?

Tags: ps4

I recently used the PS4's "Share" feature to tweet a screenshot of a Deathclaw, and I included `#Deathclaw` in the tweet. Then later, in the "Recent Activities" section of the Fallout 4 page on the XMB, I saw a card with my tweet, only the Deathclaw hashtag appeared as `#Dea***law` - the PS4 decided to replace the string "thc" with asterisks, apparently because those letters happen to be the initials of the chemical name for a psychoactive compound, which some individuals might object to seeing.

While I can see the practical applications of a language filter on social media content, the fact that it seems to operate on a regular expression that completely fails to account for context and thus triggers false positives can actually lead to the opposite effect - it took me quite a while to figure out why there were asterisks at all, and when I finally did, I realized that the word filter had actually *caused me to think about the word it was trying to censor.*

I'm a grown adult, and I don't have kids, but if I did, I'd much prefer they see the word `basement` and think about the subterranean level of a building, then that they see `ba*****t`, get confused, investigate to determine what characters were replaced with asterisks, and then are thinking about what that word represents.

A few other words that my Googling told me would receive the same treatment:

- Connection
- Doggie
- Assassin
- Prometheus
- Canal
- Cumbersome

**Is there any way to disable the word filter on the PS4's XMB/"Recent Activities" feed?**

Comment: grapefruit.....yeah ive had this trouble...the best bypass I have found is to simply put spaces between the letters...

Comment: @Firobug but that wouldn't work for a Twitter hashtag.

Comment: how about a hyphen seperating the two word#death-claw

Comment: I suppose that would circumvent the filter for that specific word, but regardless, that's an action for the *creator* of the content. I'm looking for a solution as the content *consumer*. The fact that I'm both in my example is incidental.

Comment: I feel you...best you could do is research the creator of the filter software and address it to them I think....

Comment: That's pretty ridiculous. Who knows such an opaque chemical compound? Censorship of profanities would never make any sense, especially in the gaming world

Comment: [this is still my favourite](http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2011/12/virgin-media-auto-censor-takes-the-arse-out-of-arsenal/)

Comment: Since it hasn't been spelled out yet: No, there is absolutely no way to disable the profanity filter, and although there already were MANY requests to make it client-side rather than server-side, It is being continuosly ignored. (BTW: in GTAV the word 'Rockstar' is censored)

Comment: @Emissary the final sentence in that article pretty much sums up my point - "All classic cases of how drawing attention to something makes it a million times worse."

Answer (score 2):

No.

I actually spent quite a bit of time wandering around the PS4 Manual page ([Link](http://manuals.playstation.net/)) and there is absolutely no information about it.

The best way forward with this would be to contact [Sony Support](https://www.playstation.com/en-au/get-help/contact-us/) to see if they have plans of fixing this in a future update. I highly doubt it however.

Comment: I'm glad someone finally posted an answer. While the absence of evidence does not provide evidence of absence, I appreciate the link, and the effort you put into scouring it for information. Based on the discussion/complaint threads I found when I posted this question, I agree that contacting Sony Support isn't likely to lead anywhere, but I might do it anyway, just on principle.